# Function not responding to button click in a Google HTML Dialog

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

The overall goal of this project is a story submission tracker. I have one sheet that keeps track of each story, and one sheet that keeps track of each submission.
I want to define a menu action called "New Submission" that creates a dialog that a) allows me to look up a story and display information about that story, and b) create a new submission record and update (if needed) the status of the story.

For some reason my jQuery code is not running the code I want it to run.

Most of this is taken from the sample scripts.

Here is a copy of my sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13vrk6gtLF45XCTViv6aw7dOjAR1zSIaAEqfxViM817I/edit?usp=sharing

In newsubjavascript.html, if I comment out the line with onGetStory and uncomment the alert below it, it works, but as is, it does not start the onGetStory function.

What am I missing?

Comment: You've got some `Logger.log()` statements inside of the HTML script tag.  Logger.log is only for `.gs` server side code.  Use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: I didn't realize that was a problem. I've made those changes in the script on the shared file, but it still isn't working.

Comment: See answer.  The `Logger.log()` statements might not have stopped the code from working, but you would get no log info printed to the console.

Comment: Even though you provide the entire spreadsheet, which is great, you probably got down votes (not from me) for not posting some code.  You provided the spreadsheet in just VIEW mode, which doesn't allow access to the code.

Comment: Ah! I was wondering why the downvotes. I almost thought I had provided too much context. I've updated the sharing status so hopefully everyone can see the code. Thanks for that tip!

Comment: Off-site code links are a secondary resource, which are prone to disappear, eliminating the value of the question for future readers. Also, the GAS environment isn't easily accessible to all the people following `[jquery]` who might help. Please add the relevant snippet(s) right in the question. (even if it is just the bit from Sandy's answer, it would improve the quality of your question)

Comment: @Mogsdad, thank you. I will remember to do that next time, because, as you have pointed out, the code in the linked file is not the code that was giving me grief. I did not make a new copy of the copy of the file.

Comment: Why "next time"? Questions on StackOverflow are intended to help everyone, and without perma-code this one doesn't. Please do take a moment to update it.

Comment: Because the original code no longer exists. Yes, this is a _faux pas_ on my part not to have saved the original code, but as suggestions came in, I tried them on the file linked to in the post. I have made a second copy and will endeavor to add permacode to the post as well in my next question, as I've hit another wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code:

```
 $(function() {
   $("#getstory").click(
   console.log('it ran the jquery');
     onGetStory();

     //function() {alert("JQuery Running!");}
   );};
```

to this:

```
 $( "#getstory" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  onGetStory();
});
```

And remove the `onclick()` attribute from the button.  Should be:

```
<button id="getstory" >Get Information</button>
```

Comment: I've made that change, too, but it doesn't pop up the alert. I feel like I'm missing something very basic, like a semi-colon or a bracket.

Comment: I made a copy of your spreadsheet, made those changes, and the alert did run for me.  There are still other errors in the code.  Did you get rid of the old jQuery code?

Comment: I did, and now I managed to get the alert, and hit the next wall. Thanks for getting me through this.

Comment: Ultimately, what I was missing was a close parensthesis. I'm a long time Python user, so all these semi-colons and brackets and parenthesis are driving me crazy!